# Operation with values at specific indexes in a list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm currently writing a little script in python (2.x), and there's a portion of the code that I'd like to improve without knowing how to do so.

I have a `list` of `list`s that looks like the following:

```
my_list = [["abc",1,2,"def"],["ghi",4,5,"klm"],["nop",6,7,"qrs"]]
```

I need to get the sum of all the integers at the index `1` and the sum of all the integers at the index `2`. To do so, I currently have:

```
sum1, sum2 = 0, 0
for i in my_list:
  sum1 += i[1]
  sum2 += i[2]
```

What could be a more pythonic way to do that? Maybe using `reduce` and a `lambda` function or something?

Comment: I think your current approach is fine. Readability matters, what you have here is really easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more pythonic way to do that would be using the `sum` function along with the `for ... in ...` generator and do all the work in a single line, like this:

```
sum1, sum2 = sum(x[1] for x in my_list), sum(x[2] for x in my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic would probably be list comprehensions:

```
my_list = [["abc",1,2,"def"],["ghi",4,5,"klm"],["nop",6,7,"qrs"]]
```

Summations:

```
sum1 = sum(l[1] for l in my_list)
sum2 = sum(l[2] for l in my_list)
```

Which returns:

```
sum1 = 11
sum2 = 14
```

Comment: This actually is using 2 loops now

Answer (score 0):

You could do `sum(x[1] for x in in my_list), sum(x[2] for x in my_list)` if you don't mind looping twice.

or `reduce(lambda acc, l: (acc[0] + l[1], acc[1] + l[2]), my_list, (0, 0))` if you want to do it both at once. This will return a tuple with the sum of [1] on the first element, and [2] on the second

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and list comprehension

```
>>> lst = [["abc",1,2,"def"],["ghi",4,5,"klm"],["nop",6,7,"qrs"]]
>>> [sum(i) for i in list(zip(*lst))[1:3]]
[11, 14]
```

Or use `zip` and `islice` class from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [sum(i) for i in islice(zip(*lst), 1, 3)]
[11, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner that doesn't use a generator expression. Use `zip` plus unpacking to transpose the list, then run `sum` on all the numeric columns using `map`.

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*my_list)[1:-1])
[11, 14]
```

Unfortunately it's a little wordier in 3.X since you can't slice a `zip` object.

```
a,b = map(sum, list(zip(*my_list))[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` but, since the elements in your sequence are lists, you'll need to set an initial value of `0`. In Example:

```
reduce(lambda total, list: total+list[1], my_list, 0)  # integers at index 1
reduce(lambda total, list: total+list[2], my_list, 0)  # integers at index 2
```